# Do under cabinet electrical outlets meet code and be passed by NEC in new construction?

Tags: electrical

I would like to have the quartz back splash be clear of outlets and have them in a strip at the back under side of my kitchen cabinets.  The electrician currently is telling me that these strips will not meet code guidelines.  why do they sell them if they are not safe?

Comment: See http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/gfic-requirements-for-a-kitchen-multi-outlet-strip The answer by Tester101 contains the parts of the NEC that pertain to this question.

Comment: They ARE safe. Either way, the reason they sell them is because a kitchen is not nearly the only place these are installed. See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

They are a royal PIA to install. This may be why he is discouraging you, even though he is not being truthful.

They are fine as long as they are not higher than 20" above the counter tops, and are GFI protected.

Comment: Thanks @DMoore for the downvote. Now how about you give a technical reason why?

Answer (score 0):

"at the back underside"; it is against code to mount a receptacle (GFI or otherwise) face up on the flat horizontal surface of a kitchen counter.

Comment: I read that to mean below the cabinets that are above the counter.

Comment: @TomG, he refers to the desired receptacles as an alternative to having them mounted along the back-splash. My presumption was that he needed access from the top. You can't mount them flat from below; too much potential for moisture/liquid/debris to fall/flow into them.

Comment: A strange answer to a question that is asking about mounting outlets to the underside of the cabinets, face down.

Comment: @Ecnerwal ... hmmm, I do not see the words "face down" in the original post. Are you being presumptuous or did I misinterpret the question? I think perhaps I **did** read it wrong, still kinda presumptuous.

Comment: Nor is there "face up" or "on the counter" in the question, if you'd care to look - but if they are mounted to the "back under side of the (upper, I inferred, since it's also hard to plug in to the back underside of the base cabinets) cabinets", it's **rather** hard to plug in if they are face up (and what you answered would be "on the counter" not "on the cabinets.") I simply read what the question actually said, and as such found this answer strange.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give you what a local inspector told me 3 years ago.  We had a house we were fixing up and already had a buyer lined up.  The buyer asked us to do a few things and one was stainless steel countertops and backsplash - so that it looked like an industrial kitchen.  She wanted the outlets under the cabinets.

So I submitted plans and this was an inspector that doesn't usually have much to say.

The next day he called me and said no.  With the following explanation.  Kitchen receptacles require two different branch circuits.  Also these receptacles cannot feed any cabinet lighting or receptacles.  Therefore the circuits used for the cabinet receptacles would not count and I would still need two...  So we just made holes in the sheet metal.  Looked great with plain metal covers.

Addendum with code:  NEC 210.52(b) & 210.8(A)6 & UCC Reconstruction Code

> The code requires two or more 20-ampere circuits for all receptacle
>   outlets for the small-appliance loads, including refrigeration
>   equipment, in the kitchen, dining room, pantr y, and breakfast room of
>   a dwelling unit.  The countertop receptacle outlets in kitchens must
>   be supplied by no fewer than two small-appliance branch circuits.
>   These circuits may also supply receptacle outlets in the pantry,
>   dining room, and breakfast room, as well as an electric clock
>   receptacle and electric loads associated with gas-fired appliances,
>   but these circuits are to have no other outlets.  Ground fault
>   protection is required for all receptacles serving countertop
>   surfaces.
>
> No restriction is placed on the number of outlets connected to a
>   general-lighting or small-appliance branch circuit. The minimum number
>   of receptacle out lets in a room is determined by 6 foot/ 12 foot rule
>   based on the room perimeter. It may be desirable to provide more than
>   the minimum number of receptacle outlets required, thereby further
>   reducing the need for extension cords.
>
> Exhibit 210.25 illustrates the application of the requirements. The
>   small-appliance branch circuits illustrated are not permitted to serve
>   any other outlets, such as might be connected to exhaust hoods or
>   fans, disposals, or dishwashers. The countertop receptacles are also
>   required to be supplied by these two circuits. Receptacles installed
>   to serve countertop surfaces are required to be GFCI protection. The
>   dining room switched receptacle on a 15-ampere general-purpose branch
>   circuit is permitted. The refrigerator receptacle supplied by a
>   15-ampere individual branch circuit is permitted.
>
> **Wall Counter Spaces.** A receptacle outlet shall be installed at each wall counter space that is 300 mm (12 in.) or wider. Receptacle
>   outlets shall be installed so that no point along the wall line is
>   more than 600 mm (24 in.) measured horizontally from a receptacle
>   outlet in that space.
>
> **Receptacle Outlet Location** . Receptacle outlets shall be located above, but not more than 500 mm (20in.) above, the countertop.
>   Receptacle outlets rendered not readily accessible by appliances
>   fastened in place, appliance garages, or appliances occupying
>   dedicated space shall not be considered as these required outlets.
>   Exception: To comply with the conditions specified in (a) or (b),
>   receptacle outlets shall be permitted to be mounted not more than 300
>   mm (12 in.) below the countertop. Receptacles mounted below a
>   countertop in accordance with this exception shall not be located
>   where the countertop extends more than 150 mm (6 in.) beyond its
>   support base.
>
> **Lighting & Switching** The entire lighting system is to remain separating from the 20 amp small appliance circuits. They may occupy
>   the same multi-gang box but, may not share circuits. Lighting circuits
>   are permitted to supply hood fans.

Comment: This is 100% WRONG. There is absolutely NO prohibition of "cabinet receptacles" on the small appliance branch circuits. That notion is simply absurd. My first question would have been _"Can you tell me what code section this violation falls under?"_  Inspectors CANNOT make up rules. Their job is to interpret and enforce the code, NOT create their own. The only other thing I'll say is I'm glad you are not my inspector sine this is a pretty clear cut issue that you are getting wrong.If you like I can provide the applicable code section supporting this.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey - I have seen it done... a couple times.  I have seen it knocked down by inspector a few times.  This is something they will have to ask THEIR inspector.  It's not 100% wrong.  Just because it isn't your area or what you thought.  Read closely, it clearly says "WALL counter spaces", not WALL AND CABINET.  My feelings that they shouldn't be allowed is for safety.  Most small appliances come with a 24" cord, most cabinets 18-24" over counter... So I have a feeling a lot of people would have toasters, hanging from their outlets causing shorts.

Comment: When they say "wall counter spaces" they mean counters serving wall spaces. NOT that the receptacles must physically be on the wall. It is rare to see upper cabinets more than 18-20" off the counter, so if you read my earlier post, and I see that you did, you'd see that to meet code receptacles cannot be more than 20" off the countertop surface.
It's also got NOTING to do with my area allowing it, it's got to do with your area having a rogue inspector making up his own rules.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey another thing to consider is that codes are local. Most local codes reference the NEC, but AFAIK there's nothing prevent a local government from adding it's own restrictions on top of the NEC.

Answer (score -2):

Interesting discussion, I am a Professional Engineer in South Florida, and also a private provider for building code inspections and plans examining in the electrical trade. Putting some clarification on the issue we need to make reference to **NEC 210.52 (C)(5) Receptacle Outlet Location**, basically as the rule the receptacle outlets shall be located ON or ABOVE, but not more that  20 in above the countertop. 20 in rule is based on the standard dimension measured from the coutertop to the bottom of the cabinets located above the countertop. The exception to this rule permits to be mounted not more than 12 in below the coutertop but not more than 6 in beyond its support base. Also in the exception just limited to island and peninsular countertops where no backplashers, dividers, etc, and there are no means to mount a receptacle within 20 in above the countertop, such as an overhead cabinet.
On other words this provision allows be installed on the bottom of the upper cabinets to be used as the required countertop receptacle outlets, but just limited to island and peninsular countertops, and only multioutlet assemblies. See NEC Handbook explanation following 210.52 (C)(5).
Let's discuss.

Comment: First off, this doesn't really answer the question. Second, this is **not** a discussion forum, so let's **not** discuss. Third, the exceptions you mention only apply to "*(1)Construction for the physically impaired*" and "*(2) On island and peninsular countertops where the countertop is flat across its entire surface (no backsplashes, dividers, etc.) and there are no means to mount a receptacle within 500 mm (20 in.) above the countertop, such as an overhead cabinet*". Neither of which apply to the question asked by the OP.

Comment: This discussion is great for me! I had my contractor install GFI strips under the countertops so my backsplash is neat and unobstructed. My building inspector said it wasn't code, but also said he would look the other way.
I think he just didn't know. I seen it done in a very high end home just down the street, it was approved by the previous inspector.

Comment: Im sorry it under the cabinets, not countertops where we had the GFI strips installed.

Comment: Claudication can you tell me the brand of power strips that are gfi protected...Im searching for my new kitchen...